# how to return data in reducer file using reactsj and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a problem when load my data in redux, reducer lost my data when call in my file, please help me.

my main src/index.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import store from './redux/stores'

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
 </Provider>,
 document.getElementById('root')
)
```

my file get data CampaingHeader

```
export class CampaingHeader {
private token: any 
private resp_campaing_header: any

constructor(token: any){
    this.token = token
}

/*
   get last campaing for the current user
 */
getLastCampaingHeader = async() => {
    this.resp_campaing_header = await API.get(`campaing-header-last`,{
        headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`}
    })
    return this.resp_campaing_header
 }
}
```

my files in redux

the types

/redux/types/campaing.types.tsx

```
export const SET_CAMPAING = 'SET_CAMPAING'
export const LOADING_CAMPAING = 'LOADING_CAMPAING'
export const SET_DEFAULT_CAMPAING = 'SET_DEFAULT_CAMPAING'
export const SET_ERRORS = 'SET_ERRORS'
```

the reducer
/redux/reducers/campaing.reducers.tsx
my problem is this file

```
import {
SET_DEFAULT_CAMPAING,
SET_CAMPAING,
SET_ERRORS
} from '../types/campaing.types'

const InitCampaingState = {
 answer: false,
 campaing: {}, 
 errors: {}
}

export default function(state = InitCampaingState, action: any) {
 // HERE LOAD MY DATA
 console.info(action.payload)
switch (action.type) {

    // BUT HERE NOT LOADED
    case SET_CAMPAING:
        return {
            ...state,
            answer: true,
            campaing: action.payload // ALWAYS payload is undefined
        }

    default:
        return state // AND RETURN STATE
 }
}
```

my file actions
/redux/actions/campaing.actions.tsx

```
import {
SET_CAMPAING,
SET_ERRORS,
} from '../types/campaing.types'

import {CampaingBody} from '../../userCampaings'


let token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')

let CampHeader = new CampaingBody(token)

export const RetrieveCampaing = (campaing_id: number) => (dispatch: any) => {

CampHeader.getRetrieveCBody(campaing_id)
    .then(resp =>{ 

            console.info(resp.data.data)// DATA IS LOADED HERE
            dispatch({
                type: SET_CAMPAING,
                payload: resp.data.data,// HERE LOADED DATA TOO
             })
    }).catch(err =>{
             dispatch({
                type: SET_ERRORS,
                errors: err 
             })
    })
 }
```

file when get the ID of campaing, the code below working well, pass the ID campaing to my code above in /redux/actions/campaing.actions.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
// call my actions
import {RetrieveCampaing} from '../../../../redux/actions/campaing.actions' 

const UpdateCampaing: React.FC = (props: any) => {
    React.useEffect(()=>{
     // HERE PASS DATA CORRECTLY
     let ID = GetCampID() 
     props.RetrieveCampaing(ID)
    },[])
    return(....)
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
 campaing: state.campaing
})

const mapActionToProps = {
 RetrieveCampaing   
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(UpdateCampaing)
```

and my problem is here when I try to share data from actions, using connect not working.

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
type FormData = {
 profile: Iuser
 first_name: string
 last_name: string
 email: string
 cinit: string
}

interface Icampaing {
 campaing: FormData 
}

const Personal: React.FC<Icampaing> = ({campaing})=>{
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    //MY PROBLEM IS HERE NOT LOAD DATA
    console.info('from redux')
    console.info(campaing) // RETURN DATA InitCampaingState, from my type files
  },[])
}

 return(<div>{campaing.cinit}</div>)
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) =>({
 campaing: state.campaing
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Personal)
```

my problem is in the REDUCER file, because the data is loaded, but don't return the data.

please help me, I don't know where is my error, aparentlly all working well, I means, the load data into de actions file working, but when I call the action into de PERSONAL file not working

best words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UseEffect` with empty array `[]` works like `componentDidMount`, it is called only once.

You need to add `campaing` to array and your `useEffect` hook will be called on every campaing prop change:

```
const Personal: React.FC<Icampaing> = ({campaing})=>{
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    //MY PROBLEM IS HERE NOT LOAD DATA
    console.info('from redux')
    console.info(campaing) // RETURN DATA InitCampaingState, from my type files
  },[campaing])
}
```